# Jenkins generate email when a user commits code in svn

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins.

I have created a new free style project which is checked out from SVN.

My requirement is that 
(i) I want to generate an email whenever a user has checked in code in the SVN.
(ii) The email should be in a proper format(Like html formatting)

I have just started using Jenkins today so let me tell you that i do not have much idea :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send an email, every time a commit happens in svn, then I would solve this in svn. Use a [post commit hook](https://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101) for this

If you want to send an email each time a build in jenkins happens, add the mail command to your ant build script, `build.xml`. There is a special [Mail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) for this.

You may say that it does not matter whether the email is sent on svn commit or on jenkins build. But this is not exactly true: Normally you configure jenkins in a way that it polls svn for new commits, let's say every 30 minutes. If new commits happened jenkins will trigger the build script to run. But note that in 30 minutes more than 1 commit could happen. Therefore you'll have to decide if you want to send a email on every commit or every build:

On every build  : use a special [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) in your build.xml

On every commit : use a [svn post-commit hook](https://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101)

Comment: Thanks :) But if I wanted Jenkins to monitor my SVN repo and send emails every time there is a commit, how can i do that ?

Comment: I've added a little bit more text. Does this already answer your question? You should use a svn hook script in favour of jenkins to send mail on *every* commit

Comment: I would like the email to be generated on every commit.

Comment: have you access to the svn **server**?

Comment: Yes. I have access to the SVN server

Comment: Then create a svn post commit hook. you can follow the tutorial that I've linked

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way we can do it in Jenkins ?

Comment: Will your answer be the same if SVN repository was replaced by GIT repo ?

Comment: yes. that's because jenkins **polls** for new commits, the scm software won't give a signal to jenkins. While this could be done using hooks, it makes no sense. Why not just using the scm hooks (they are available in git as well)? They are perfect for this

Comment: Thanks a Lot Friend. Just 1 last stupid question. You mentioned that Jenkins can polls for new svn commits. Ho can I do it ?

Comment: :) nono the questions aren't stupid. I'm familiar with jenkins only a half year. can remember me struggling to make it work :) . I can say one thing: If you once got it work it's really easy to understand. .... However, to make the polling work, create a new job, and go to `Configure`, then `source code management` . add your repo url (and credentials if necessary). Then go to `build triggers` and use `poll scm` .. here you can use a cronjob like syntax.. for example : `*/30 * * * *` if it should poll every 30 minutes